# Dart - How to order datetime objects?

Tags: dart, flutter

Using Flutter/Dart (newbie). I need to store users results in a game (score, time and name). I presume a GameResult class is the way to go?

I then need to order on each users results on date/time (newest to oldest) to display a results table. How can I order on datetime values?

Answer (score 18):

The Dart [DateTime](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) class is [Comparable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) to other `DateTime` objects, so you can use `dateTime1.compareTo(dateTime2)` to compare two points in time.

Example:

```
class Result implements Comparable<Result> {
   final String name;
   final int score;       
   final DateTime time;
   Result(this.name, this.score, this.time);

   int compareTo(Result other) {
     int order = other.score.compareTo(score);
     if (order == 0) order = time.compareTo(other.time);
     return order;
   }

   String toString() => "Result($name, score: $score, time: $time)";
 }
```

This creates a class where instances can be compared to each other.
The order is first by reverse `score` (higher score before lower score) and for equal scores, it sorts the earlier results before later results.

The [`Comparable.compareTo`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html) method is specified to return a negative number if the receiver is "before" the argument in the order, zero if they have the same order, and a positive number if the receiver is after the argument.

Integers are comparable too, and by using `other.score.compareTo(score)` instead of the other way around, we effectively switch the ordering of the scores - integers default to lower values before higher values).

When the `Result` class is comparable to itself, you can sort a `List<Result>` as just:

```
var results = <Result>[
   Result("Me", 0, DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 1))),
   Result("Me again", 0, DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 2))),
   Result("You", 1000000, DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 24))), 
];
results.sort();
print(results.join("\n"));
```

This prints:

```
Result(You, score: 1000000, time: 2018-10-23 15:34:16.532)
Result(Me again, score: 0, time: 2018-10-24 13:34:16.532)
Result(Me, score: 0, time: 2018-10-24 14:34:16.531)
```

You win by score. My earlier zero-score is before my later one.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for a complete example, I was pretty much able to cut and paste into my app. I cannot upvote you at the moment, I will when I get sufficient privilege.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to evaluate the dates as **Epoch DateTime** `millisecondsSinceEpoch` then sort as standard **int** values.

With this approach you can **sort an entire list in one line**...

```
result.sort((a,b) => a.date.millisecondsSinceEpoch.compareTo(b.date.millisecondsSinceEpoch));
```

Here is a complete example using the Game Result scenario

```
// Create the game result object
class Result{

    Result(this.name, this.score, this.date);
    String name;
    int score;
    DateTime date;

    @override    
    String toString() => '$name  $score  $date';
}


// Create a list to put the results in
List<Result> result = [];


// Populate the list with results
result..add( Result('Tom',  850, DateTime.tryParse('2020-01-10')))
      ..add( Result('Dic',   600, DateTime.tryParse('2020-01-03')))
      ..add( Result('Harry', 450, DateTime.tryParse('2020-01-05')));

// print the unsorted list
print(result);

// Sort the list by datetime property
result.sort((a,b) => a.date.millisecondsSinceEpoch.compareTo(b.date.millisecondsSinceEpoch));


// print the sorted list
print(result);
```